# Use cellular for internet while local (non-routable) ethernet is active

Tags: ethernet, windows-10-v1903, cellular-internet

I am currently working at a customer's setting up and testing a machine. I need local ethernet to the machine so I can test. The machine network is closed and has no access to the internet (non-routable). I am connected to a managed switch in the machine (though a non-managed switch sits between, so my colleagues can have access to).

In order to be able to work at a meaningful speed, I have an LTE stick attached to my laptop so I can have access to the internet (if possible I'd like to share it via a local switch with my colleagues).

I've seen that Windows 10 has an issue with that situation and that I can fix it by setting a registry key "IgnoreNonRoutableEthernet" to 1. Actually once I set a static IP, Subnet and Gateway for my local ethernet adapter, Windows says I'm connected to the internet via the LTE stick.

But when I try to access any website, it just instantly pops up "the server cannot be found". When I deactivate Ethernet, it works.

Anyone got an idea how to fix that? It would be a real setback if I had to deactivate ethernet everytime I need to look up something. I can access the local network (ping works) but it seems like Windows cannot reach any internet-based address. I tried `nslookup` and set my DNS to Cloudflare's DNS (1.1.1.1). Works until I enable ethernet, then it cannot find the server anymore.

Comment: If it's "non-routable" why does it even have a gateway present in the first place?

Comment: If I don't set a gateway, it seems that Windows doesn't get that it cannot route through it and thus shows "no internet" and the Ethernet as my primary network. When I set one, it switches over to Cellular and has internet, but cannot find any servers.

Comment: Also seems like a DNS issue.

Comment: Yeah most likely. Latest research I've done was that 1903 still has some network-related bugs. Maybe it's because of that. Windows really is a mess... Well, I got the customer's wifi working, so I have internet now. But that's not given all times, so it would still be good to know how to fix this issue...